# SwiftUI NavigationSplitView on iPad: remove accent from selected item in Sidebar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I am adopting `NavigationSplitView` for an app to be used on an iPad as well as on an iPhone.

In my code below, I want to highlight the the selected item in the Sidebar *only* with the word "Selected".

When running for iPad Air 5th generation, the Sidebar appears differently between the preview and the simulator:

- In the preview, the behaviour is exactly what I want: the word "Selected" indicates the item visible in the detail view (see picture below without blue border).
- However, when running on the simulator, an accent rectangle is visible around the selection (see picture below *with* blue border). **My goal is to remove this rectangle.**

In fact, if we remove the `.listRowBackground()` modifier, in the preview the accent is light gray, in the simulator is blue.

Some things I tried:

1. Replacing `.listRowBackground(EmptyView())` with `.listRowBackground(Collar.clear)`: no success.
2. Using `.accentColor(.clear)`: it does not work (the rectangle gets white), and moreover it is being deprecated, so I want to avoid it.
3. Adding `.tint(.clear)` and `listItemTint(.clear)`: no success.
4. Replacing `List` with `ForEach`, but then I have to re-create the layout of the rows, and the result is not the same.

I need to keep the "yellow" background.

Does anyone know how to remove that rectangle?

My code:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var selected: MyContent?
    
    let list = [MyContent("First"), MyContent("Second"), MyContent("Third")]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationSplitView {
            
            List(list, selection: $selected) { item in
                
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.title)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(selected == item ? "Selected" : "")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
                .listRowBackground(EmptyView())
                
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .background(.yellow)
            
        } detail: {
            if let selected {
                Text("Detail of \(selected.title)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyContent: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    
    init(_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve (OK in the preview):
[image]

The rectangle I want to remove (running on the simulator):
[image]

Deploying for iOS 16.0 on Xcode 14.

Comment: I'm also encountering the same issue. No solution yet, and I'm assuming it's simulator bug. I also tried using UISplitViewController + UIHostingController, but the result was same. From view hierarchy analysis, the cause is in `_UIFocusHaloView` which seems to be used for halo effect when using a hardware or keyboard, which requires quite a lot of effort to safely disable it. Good news is that this bug only happens in simulator and not on device.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying .accentColor under the List, matching it with the background. It works in my case:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var selected: MyContent?
    
    let list = [MyContent("First"), MyContent("Second"), MyContent("Third")]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationSplitView {
            
            List(list, selection: $selected) { item in
                
                NavigationLink(value: item) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.title)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(selected == item ? "Selected" : "")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
                
            }
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .background(.yellow)
            .accentColor(.yellow) //<-- this
            
        } detail: {
            if let selected {
                Text("Detail of \(selected.title)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```